# Backlight asus zenbook ux510uw

Tags: brightness, asus, backlight

I installed elementary on my new PC and the. To make everything work I followed this [tuto](http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/asus-ux510uw-n-ubuntu-16-04-review-setup.796871/)

For my hotkeys I modified `/etc/default/grub`

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi="
```

after I created the file `20-intel.conf` in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/`

```
# begin file contents
Section "Device"
Identifier "card0"
Driver "intel"
Option "Backlight" "intel_backlight"
BusID "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
# end file contents
```

Now when I use my hotkeys to adjust the brightness, the indicator changes but not the brightness.

Comment: I have the same problem in my Zenbook UX305U. Have you found a solution? Thanks.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/7978)